# Can not merge Stack Overflow accounts

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I have two Stack Overflow accounts. Now I want to merge those two accounts. How can I do this?

I followed these steps:

- Step 1 : Create Account
- Step 2 : login with https://stackoverflow.com/users/1562574/dipak
- Step 3 : Click "my logins" in the profile page
- Step 4 : Click "Add more logins" in the popup
- Step 5 : Login with my another account

I found the above steps from : https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge

But I can't merge the accounts. No error is displayed. I simply login with second user when I try to merge them.

Comment: I just experienced the very same thing. You accepted an answer, but I still don't know the answer to your question.

Comment: PS they turned out to be merged later on the day. It would be nice to get more feedback on the status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went ahead and merged your accounts manually, but you should be aware that the automated merging won't happen instantly - you'll want to give it a day to be sure the scheduled task has time to run. You did get this to work once before - this is the second account you've had merged into yours, but the first to be done manually.

You seem to have yet another account floating around - you might want to give the automated process another shot & get that one rolled in too...

Comment: I've just merged my accounts following the above instructions. I'll wait a day or so to see if they roll up. Quick question though- does your reputation get merged as well?

Comment: Yes it does, @gene

Comment: I'm having a similar issue -- I've got two accounts and I'd like to merge them; the issue here however is that the account I want to merge registers as just a browser-based user and (I assume) not a regular user? Can you help?

Comment: @Miles: Go [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge), and click the link for the form at the bottom.

Comment: The 2nd user is showing as unregistered, so I'm not really sure how to log in with that. :/  http://stackoverflow.com/users/551628/mil3s   I realize that sounds ridiculous...

Comment: @Miles No, happens all the time. Just mention that when contacting us, and we'll take care of it. I've gone ahead and merged your accounts now, but for anyone else reading this...

Comment: Thanks @Shog. I appreciate it!