# Merging unregistered user

Tags: support, user-accounts, login, unregistered-users

[image]

In SO, I saw my duplicate account saying "Unregistered". I don't remember creating it. I tried to merge the account with following link : https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-logins. But couldn't.

How can I merge / access / delete this duplicate account?

I have looked at a few posts but have found no success:

[Can not merge Stack Overflow accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156531/can-not-merge-stack-overflow-accounts)

https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-logins

[What does it mean when someone's an Unregistered User?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68524/unregistered-user)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/583900/pradip-kharbuja
The next account.

Comment: You followed the instructions on: http://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge ? How long ago?

Comment: tried just today  ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

Comment: @Air: The answer there just says to do what this user already did. That's not terribly helpful, and suggests this is a more detailed support case.

Comment: @NathanTuggy This question has had no activity in years and the "next account" is gone - suggesting Oded (or another staffer) resolved the specific support issue long ago. This probably should have been handled via "contact us" to begin with, but in case users with similar problems find this in search results, better to have it point to a FAQ (more likely to remain current/accurate) than sit here as a dead end. If you think the FAQ answer is not helpful *for future visitors* - it's CW, you know what to do.

Comment: @Air: So close as no-repro, or nothing.